# Does fairness guarantee FIFO scheduling?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, reentrantlock

Directly from this [website](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/using-reentrant-locks-for-thread-synchronization/):

> But if we are specifying the fairness parameter as “true” while
>   creating a new ReentrantLock object, it gives us the guaranty that the
>   longest waiting thread will get the lock next. Sounds pretty nice
>   right?

I thought that it is never guaranteed, it just influences the decision of the scheduler. Isn't it or the website above-linked is actually saying the truth?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [API documentation for ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) says (my emphasis):

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many
>   threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often
>   much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller
>   variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation.
>   *Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of
>   thread scheduling.* Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may
>   obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are
>   not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the
>   untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will
>   succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.

So it would seem the website you quote is oversimplifying a bit.